# I have a jailed user , that cannot ping hostnames (only ip addresses)

Tags: linux, dns, centos, ping, jail

I have a jailed user , that cannot ping hostnames (only ip addresses):

```
[dimitar@nl ~]$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Dig is working without any problem:

```
[dimitar@nl ~]$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.4 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 14169
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             300     IN      A       173.194.78.101
google.com.             300     IN      A       173.194.78.113
google.com.             300     IN      A       173.194.78.139
google.com.             300     IN      A       173.194.78.100
google.com.             300     IN      A       173.194.78.102
google.com.             300     IN      A       173.194.78.138

;; Query time: 11 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun Jul 28 15:49:06 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 124
```

Any idea ? Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the name resolution mechanism in the jail: like the (local?) copy of /etc/resolv.conf

(This answer is based on a lot of assumptions, because the question is not very precise. If the configuration of the name resolution is ok, I would do a 'nslookup google.com' or even a 'strace -f nslookup google.com' to see where it fails.)

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf is there : [dimitar@nl ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Comment: Also in the jail? Can the jailed user access it? If so, try the 'strace -f ...'

Comment: Sure . :) /home/dimitar/etc/resolv.conf and the file have a chmod 644